# Jackson annotation being ignored in case of representation query params as object

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jackson

So there is a simple GET endpoint which is able to accept some url-params. In order to work with them in more elegant way the POJO is being used. Also, all the POJO fields are annotated with swagger annotations

```
@GetMapping
public Object getSomething(@Valid QueryParams queryParams,
                           HttpServletRequest request) {
   // do smth with queryParams
   return something
}

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@ApiModel(value = "QueryParams", description = "some description")
public class QueryParams {
    //some other fields

    @ApiModelProperty(value = "Some description", example = "false")
    @JsonDeserialize(using = StrictBooleanDeserializer.class)
    @JsonProperty("is_archived")
    private Boolean isArchived;
    
    //some other fields
}
```

The problem is that no Jackson annotation is actually applied to annotated fields. The code inside StrictBooleanDeserializer is not invoked.

I know there is the following workaround

```
@Autowired
private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

@GetMapping
public Object getSomething(Map<String, String> params,
                           HttpServletRequest request) {
   QueryParams queryParams = objectMapper.convertValue(params, QueryParams.class)
   // do smth with queryParams
   return something
}
```

But in this way we lose the declarative validation and all the swagger descriptions.
I think there has to be a way to use all the mentioned features together without much of overhead.

Comment: Same problem here, did you find any solutions to this ?